# Numba pickle error: can't pickle class <class-name>: it's not the same object as class-name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, numba

I'm trying to learn numba, and so as an intro exercise, I wrote a simple orbit solver:

```python
    import numba as nb
    import numpy as np
    from timeit import default_timer as timer

    spec = [('x0', nb.types.float64),
        ('y0', nb.types.float64),
        ('vx0', nb.types.float64),
        ('vy0', nb.types.float64),
        ('mass', nb.types.float64),
        ('ax', nb.types.float64),
        ('ay', nb.types.float64),
        ('x', nb.types.float64[:]),
        ('y', nb.types.float64[:]),
        ('vx', nb.types.float64[:]),
        ('vy', nb.types.float64[:])]
    @nb.jitclass(spec)
    class CelestialBody():
        def __init__(self, x0, y0, vx0, vy0, mass):
            self.x0 = x0
            self.y0 = y0
            self.vx0 = vx0
            self.vy0 = vy0
            self.mass = mass
            self.ax = 0.0
            self.ay = 0.0

    @nb.jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
    def orbit(bodies, delta_t, nsteps):
        # Set up position arrays
        for j in range(len(bodies)):
            bodies[j].x = np.zeros(nsteps, dtype=np.float64)
            bodies[j].y = np.zeros(nsteps, dtype=np.float64)
            bodies[j].vx = np.zeros(nsteps, dtype=np.float64)
            bodies[j].vy = np.zeros(nsteps, dtype=np.float64)
            bodies[j].x[0] = bodies[j].x0
            bodies[j].y[0] = bodies[j].y0
            bodies[j].vx[0] = bodies[j].vx0
            bodies[j].vy[0] = bodies[j].vy0
        # Loop over every time step (skip 0 since we have x0 and y0)
        for i in range(0, nsteps-1):
            # Get gravitational acceleration for each body at current time
            for j in range(len(bodies)):
                # Reset accelerations
                bodies[j].ax = 0.0
                bodies[j].ay = 0.0
                for k in range(len(bodies)):
                    if j != k:
                        # Get distance between objects
                        dx = bodies[j].x[i] - bodies[k].x[i]
                        dy = bodies[j].y[i] - bodies[k].y[i]
                        d = np.sqrt(dx**2. + dy**2.)
                        # Get acceleration
                        a = -bodies[k].mass / d**2.
                        # Separate into x and y components
                        theta = np.arctan2(dy, dx)
                        bodies[j].ax += a * np.cos(theta)
                        bodies[j].ay += a * np.sin(theta)
            # Update positions
            for j in range(len(bodies)):
                bodies[j].vx[i+1] += bodies[j].vx[i] + bodies[j].ax * delta_t
                bodies[j].vy[i+1] += bodies[j].vy[i] + bodies[j].ay * delta_t
                bodies[j].x[i+1] += bodies[j].x[i] + bodies[j].vx[i] * delta_t    +\
                                0.5 * bodies[j].ax * delta_t**2. 
                bodies[j].y[i+1] += bodies[j].y[i] + bodies[j].vy[i] * delta_t + 0.5 *\
                                bodies[j].ay * delta_t**2
        return bodies



    for i in range(10):
        # Set up celestial bodies
        sun     = CelestialBody(0., 0., 0., 0., 1.)
        earth   = CelestialBody(1., 0., 0., 6.33, 3.00e-6)

        bodies = [sun, earth]

        # Set up time info
        tf = 100. 
        delta_t = tf / 365.
        nsteps = int(tf / delta_t)

        # Orbit
        start = timer()
        bodies = orbit(bodies, delta_t, nsteps)
        end = timer()
        print('Time to run: %f' % (end - start))
```

The code works and runs without numba. When I add numba, I am able to jit both my class and function, and it runs just fine, providing a good speed up. However, when I try to cache the jitt'ed function using cache=True, I get a KeyError:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/caching.py", line 482, in save
data_name = overloads[key]
KeyError: ((reflected list(instance.jitclass.CelestialBody#2cef1b8<x0:float64,
 y0:float64,vx0:float64,vy0:float64,mass:float64,ax:float64,ay:float64,
x:array(float64, 1d, A),y:array(float64, 1d, A),vx:array(float64, 1d, A),
vy:array(float64, 1d, A)>), float64, int64), ('x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu',
'skylake', '+adx,+aes,+avx,+avx2,-avx512bitalg,-avx512bw,-avx512cd,-avx512dq,
-avx512er,-avx512f,-avx512ifma,-avx512pf,-avx512vbmi,-avx512vbmi2,-avx512vl,
-avx512vnni,-avx512vpopcntdq,+bmi,+bmi2,-cldemote,+clflushopt,-clwb,-clzero,+cmov,
+cx16,+f16c,+fma,-fma4,+fsgsbase,-gfni,+invpcid,-lwp,+lzcnt,+mmx,+movbe,-movdir64b,
-movdiri,-mwaitx,+pclmul,-pconfig,-pku,+popcnt,-prefetchwt1,+prfchw,-ptwrite,
-rdpid,+rdrnd,+rdseed,-rtm,+sahf,+sgx,-sha,-shstk,+sse,+sse2,+sse3,+sse4.1,
+sse4.2,-sse4a,+ssse3,-tbm,-vaes,-vpclmulqdq,-waitpkg,-wbnoinvd,-xop,+xsave,
+xsavec,+xsaveopt,+xsaves'))
```

I realize most of the above is compiler flags and such and probably unnecessary, but I wasn't sure so I figured I'd include it.

There's also a pickle error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.CelestialBody'>: it's not the same object as __main__.CelestialBody
```

I've tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412787/picklingerror-cant-pickle-class-decimal-decimal-its-not-the-same-object), but as far as I can tell there's no import error, and I haven't messed with any of the modules I'm importing. I'm also not running in a jupyter notebook, just a terminal. My guess is that it has something to do with the class "signature" before and after it's compiled, and pickle is getting confused about the change. I am able to get caching to work when a class is not used.

I'm using Python version 3.6.7, numpy version 1.15.4, and numba version 0.42.1

So, my question is what is causing this pickle error that is preventing caching? Thank you!

Comment: In numba 0.45.1 I get `NumbaWarning: Cannot cache compiled function "orbit" as it uses dynamic globals (such as ctypes pointers and large global arrays)`. I guess that you cannot cache a function, if one its arguments is a list of objects.

Comment: This thread might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098254/passing-a-class-object-as-a-function-argument-in-numba-optimized-python