# Numba jit() function signature for function returning jitclass

Tags: python, numba

If I define a jitclass:

```
SPEC = [ ... ]
@jitclass
class Foo:
    ...
```

How can I specify the type signature for a jit-ed function returning a class instance. When I try:

```
@jit("Foo(float32[:])")
def some_function(a: np.ndarray): ...
```

I get `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined` even though it is declared just above.

Comment: According to [doc](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/jit-compilation.html#jit-functions), types are assumed to come from `numba.types`. For a moment, thought that taking away quotes worked, but the problem is that python treats that as a call to jitclass constructor, which fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/49102638/435563

Try the following:

```
@jit(Foo.class_type.instance_type(float32[:]))
def some_function(a: np.ndarray): ...
```